# Launch PowerApps barcode scanner on Windows 10

Tags: qr-code, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

In PowerApps there is the very useful Barcode Scanner control. But it's available only on iOS or Android. Do some ways exist to use this control to scan QR-codes via a canvas app on a Windows 10 tablet?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Microsoft documentation, The barcode scanner control is only supported on Android and iOS devices. All other platforms will show a warning that some features of the app won't work.

If you have windows 10 tablet, you can test your app and check if you have any limation since not all features are guaranteed to work.

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-new-barcode-scanner